# Typhoon Kubernetes Error : module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap: Still creating... [22m0s elapsed]

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, typhoon-kubernetes

I am trying to create a typhoon K8s cluster using [typhoon](https://typhoon.psdn.io/flatcar-linux/aws/) via terraform.

I am trying to create Kubernetes cluster on AWS using typhoon and my progress is still here [link](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/terraform-kitchen/tree/master/aws/task-021-k8s-cluster-typhoon-IN-PROGRESS)

Strangely, the output gets stuck for hours at this error

```sh
module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap: Still creating... [22m0s elapsed]
```

- I am not sure what the issue here is?

I have followed all the steps as per the document but this keeps happening. Also checked the closed issues on the Github repo [link](https://github.com/poseidon/typhoon/) and found some which are similar but none could help.

Following is the output of the `TF_LOG=TRACE terraform apply`

```sh
module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap: Provisioning with 'remote-exec'...
2020-07-17T23:44:45.562+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:45 [DEBUG] Connecting to 54.174.116.142:22 for SSH
module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap (remote-exec):   Host: 54.174.116.142
module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap (remote-exec):   User: core
module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap (remote-exec):   Password: false
module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap (remote-exec):   Private key: false
module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap (remote-exec):   Certificate: false
module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: true
module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
2020-07-17T23:44:45.755+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:45 [DEBUG] Connection established. Handshaking for user core
2020/07/17 23:44:46 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provisioner.remote-exec (close)" is waiting for "module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap"
2020-07-17T23:44:47.191+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:47 [DEBUG] Telling SSH config to forward to agent
2020-07-17T23:44:47.191+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:47 [DEBUG] Setting up a session to request agent forwarding
2020-07-17T23:44:47.818+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:47 [INFO] agent forwarding enabled
2020-07-17T23:44:47.818+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:47 [DEBUG] starting ssh KeepAlives
2020-07-17T23:44:47.818+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:47 [DEBUG] opening new ssh session
module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap (remote-exec): Connected!
2020/07/17 23:44:47 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider.null (close)" is waiting for "module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap"
2020-07-17T23:44:48.013+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:48 [DEBUG] Starting remote scp process:  scp -vt /tmp
2020-07-17T23:44:48.212+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:48 [DEBUG] Started SCP session, beginning transfers...
2020-07-17T23:44:48.212+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:48 [DEBUG] Beginning file upload...
2020-07-17T23:44:48.417+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:48 [DEBUG] SCP session complete, closing stdin pipe.
2020-07-17T23:44:48.417+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:48 [DEBUG] Waiting for SSH session to complete.
2020-07-17T23:44:48.622+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:48 [ERROR] scp stderr: "Sink: C0644 41 terraform_187433809.sh\n"
2020-07-17T23:44:48.622+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:48 [DEBUG] opening new ssh session
2020-07-17T23:44:49.033+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:49 [DEBUG] starting remote command: chmod 0777 /tmp/terraform_187433809.sh
2020/07/17 23:44:49 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" is waiting for "module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap"
2020-07-17T23:44:49.238+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:49 [DEBUG] remote command exited with '0': chmod 0777 /tmp/terraform_187433809.sh
2020-07-17T23:44:49.238+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:49 [DEBUG] opening new ssh session
2020-07-17T23:44:49.646+0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: remote-exec-provisioner (internal) 2020/07/17 23:44:49 [DEBUG] starting remote command: /tmp/terraform_187433809.sh
2020/07/17 23:44:49 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)"
2020/07/17 23:44:51 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provisioner.remote-exec (close)" is waiting for "module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap"
2020/07/17 23:44:52 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider.null (close)" is waiting for "module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap"
2020/07/17 23:44:54 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" is waiting for "module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap"
2020/07/17 23:44:54 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)"
module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
2020/07/17 23:44:56 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provisioner.remote-exec (close)" is waiting for "module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap"
2020/07/17 23:44:57 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider.null (close)" is waiting for "module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap"
2020/07/17 23:44:59 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" is waiting for "module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap"
2020/07/17 23:44:59 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)"
2020/07/17 23:45:01 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provisioner.remote-exec (close)" is waiting for "module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap"
2020/07/17 23:45:02 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider.null (close)" is waiting for "module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap"
2020/07/17 23:45:04 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" is waiting for "module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap"
2020/07/17 23:45:04 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)"
module.tempest.null_resource.bootstrap: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
```

and this continues ENDLESSLY

- Also the `domain` which got created `k8s118.devops.link` is not resolving publically

```sh
dig k8s118.devops.link

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> k8s118.devops.link
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 595
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;k8s118.devops.link.            IN      A

;; Query time: 495 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Sat Jul 18 00:36:07 +04 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47
```

Answer (score 3):

This is all Terraform. You can see what's going on by enabling [TRACE](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html) logs in Terraform

```sh
TF_LOG=TRACE terraform plan
TF_LOG=TRACE terraform apply
```

You can also see  what's going on in the AWS console. Are you EC2 instances being created? What DNS entries are being created in Route53? What VPCs are being created? etc.

You can go through the list ️️ of resources being created if you look at the [TF files](https://github.com/poseidon/typhoon/tree/master/aws/container-linux/kubernetes).

Comment: ahh okay. Thanks a lot @Rico, let me follow this procedure and come up with a more detailed explanation of the situation and update here.

Comment: @ Rico  i have updated the question with the trace logs and the ReadMe.md with the set of resources being created. Would you be able to help with this ?

Comment: do you have an idea what this server is `54.174.116.142`?

Comment: this is the kube-controller server. Its in one of the [images](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/terraform-kitchen/blob/master/aws/task-021-k8s-cluster-typhoon-IN-PROGRESS/.ReadMe_images/EC2-instances.png) which i gave in ReadMe.md

Comment: Also why is the dig command not resolving. Isn’t it expected to resolve as the dns record was created.

Comment: It looks like it's running this on your server `/tmp/terraform_187433809.sh` can you check what that is? There must be some log somewhere.  Regarding the domain. Do you own `devops.link`? If you are using Route53 you need to update the nameservers on your domain registrar

Comment: Ahh okay. Thanks a lot @Rico. I will check on the server for any logs and what that script is. WRT the domain, i am using route53, i do not actually own devops.link, i thought it will be done here with dns zone only. 1) how do i do that? 2) I did not understand the nameservers part as well.

Comment: for the domains read this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html